# Add file to document library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, document-library, file

I have a default team site and want to create a new text file in it's document library programmatically.

```
SPList srcList = srcWeb.Lists["Documents"]
```

Returns a valid list. I can loop the listItems here,

```
foreach (SPListItem item in srcList.Items)
```

Get the `File` for each item and even the contents of each file.

However, even though I can get existing files, I cannot seem to create a new file in this list.

What I tried:

`srcWeb.Folders["Documents"]` - returns null

`SPListItem destLI = srcWeb.Lists["Documents"].Items.Add();` - gives me a valid list item with a NULL `.File`. (Which I cannot initialize, since `SPFile` does not contructor).

`srcWeb.Lists["Documents"].Folders.Add` - I DO NOT want to create a new folder but simply add files to the root directory of the list.

`POST` technique (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms454491(v=office.14).aspx) I'd rather avoid this because I will add Metadata in the future.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, found it.

`srcList.RootFolder.Files.Add` was what I was looking for.